# jqplot label one point on the plot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have a figure including two lines (one horizontal line, and one parabolic curve), and I would like to show the value of the crossing over point as well as label it with text "MSY". I tried to use the option `pointLabels`, but it seemed like I did not find the right way. Can anyone give me some hints? Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/JWhmQ/289/) of the problem.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var s1 = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.036], [2.0, 0.064], [3.0, 0.084], [4.0, 0.096], [5.0, 0.1], [6.0, 0.096], [7.0, 0.084], [8.0, 0.063], [9.0, 0.036], [10.0, 0.0]];

    $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            showMarker: false,
            pointLabels: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: 'X label',
                pad: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: 'Y label',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'ne',
            placement: 'inside',
            fontSize: '11px'
        },
        canvasOverlay: {
            show: true,
            objects: [
                {
                horizontalLine: {
                    y: 0.1,
                    color: 'rgb(100, 55, 124)',
                    show: true,
                }}
            ]
        },
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            labels: [[5, 0.10]],
            hideZeros: true
        }
    })
})​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight solution but assuming the parabola to be uniform. I just made some assumptions to calculate the vertex of a parabola. Its just an approximation .And prepared an array that could be feeded to Series label.

```
var k = Math.round(s1.length / 2); //Assuming your Parabola to be uniform
    var l = [];
    var i=0;
    while(i<(k-1))
    {
    l.push("");
        i++;
    }
    l.push('MSY');
```

Now we have the l array now I would feed it to the series option so as to get the required result.

```
 series: [
            {
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                labels: l
            }}],
```

I have made the necessary changes in fiddle and updated it http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/292/ . 
I would recommend you to find a small plugin or build a small script which would give you the tip or vertex of the parabola and use the above for that. It would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. A question, is there a way to run this push function 'l.push('MSY')' without looping 'k' steps?

Comment: Actually if you look at those k steps I actually add just blank data to the array so that the position of the "MSY" comes at the center. See Since there were ten values to the Graph. I considered the center point to be k= 10/2 and rounded it off. Result was 6. Then the l array was formed which should be like ["","","","","","MSY"]. This is to be feeded to the series. So have to iterate it that way. Hope this is clear. But I would recommend you to get some formula to find it out if the graph is dynamic.. in the near future. For time being this wont cause problems. :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, my parabola is always uniform in this case. So I am wondering is it possible to use insert "MSY" directly to I vector at position K?

Comment: You have to push some element right :) So let it be. Is the `while` causing any problem ?

Comment: @tao.hong I checked out. This is the only way to fill up an array.

Comment: The while function is good, just sometimes I have to loop it over 10K times. But really thanks for the help!